# Can terminal be used to find files on MBP?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal

Can terminal be used to find where Thunderbird keeps email files?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need Google, not terminal ;) [Mozilla KB](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Mac_OS_X) says it will be one of these:

- `~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/<Profile name>/`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Thunderbird/Profiles/<Profile name>/`

`~` is your Home folder.

For finding files from terminal you may use the tool called `find`. A quick cheat sheet:

```
find [path] [-maxdepth depth] [-ctime n] [-size n[ckMG]] [-type type] [-perm permissions] [-exec command {} \;]
```

(these are just basic arguments, `find` is really powerful)

Comment: +1 for the first sentence - it made me laugh - and then for answering the question anyway.